# How to add a opaque button on background image in html?

Tags: html, css

[image: Website]

I want to add an opaque button in such a way that I can see the background image and the button can still be clicked, like the sign-in button in the above image. How would I go about this?

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Subjects</title>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color:black;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
            }
            .title {
                height: 62px;
                width: 231px;
                background-color:#446CB3;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
                margin-top: 81px;
                margin-left: 28px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="title">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like... a transparent link?

```css
body {
  background: #ccc url('http://lorempixel.com/g/1024/768') no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="alert('It\'s working!')">Transparent link</a>
```

Or an invisible link?

```css
body {
  background: #ccc url('http://lorempixel.com/g/1024/768') no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="alert('It\'s working!')">Invisible link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to use `rgba` colors in background of your button:

```
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
```

Example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Subjects</title>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color:black;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
            }
            .title {
                height: 20px;
                width: 231px;
                background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
                border: solid 2px #fff;
                border-radius: 4px;
                margin-top: 81px;
                margin-left: 28px;
                color: #fff;
                text-align:center;
                padding:16px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="title">
            Sign up!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the button element an opacity property

https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_image_transparency.asp